# Knockout Js: foreachBinding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have object **models** which is of format below,

```
models:
   [
      0: {
         [functions]: ,
         __proto__: { },
         Main: "Sample",
         sub: [
            0: " Sub1",
            1: " Sub2",
            2: " sub3",
            3: " sub4",
            4: " sub5",
            5: " sub6",
            6: " sub7",
            7: " sub8",
            length: 8
         ]
      },
      1: { },
      2: { },
```

I have listed first three elements of the object as sample. Also first element is elaborated. I am trying to list this as below.

```
Main 1
 sub details
Main 2
 sub details
```

I have tried like, I could not figure out why my data binding is not working. Following code not displaying anything in the screen.

```
            <td>
                <ul class="tree">
                    <li data-bind="foreach: models" >
                        <span data-bind="text: $data[$index].main"></span>
                        <ul data-bind="foreach: subDetails in models.sub">
                            <li><span data-bind="text: $data[$index].sub"></span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
```

Please check my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MJSuriya/6muqxue3/) here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of issues with *your* [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MJSuriya/6muqxue3/). Here is a list -

- You have written `ko.applybindigs` which should have been `ko.applyBindings`
- The `model` should be a part of your viewModel, so you will need to attach that variable to your viewModel. Like `var self = this;  self.model = []...`. Declaring it just as a private `var` will not expose it to the knockout bindings and hence that will not work.
- Once inside of a `foreach` binding, you don't need `$index` to access the objects inside of the array, just accessing them by their names is all you need. So `<span data-bind="text: $data[$index].Main"></span>` is replaced by `<span data-bind="text: Main"></span>`
- You have another `foreach` nested inside the outer one, there too you have used `$index` accessor which really isn't necessary. To add to that `<ul data-bind="foreach: subdetails in model.sub">` can easily be replaced with `<ul data-bind="foreach: Sub">` (please also notice the typo in `sub` which should have been `Sub`)

Corrected fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p5oL3wf5/)

Comment: You fail to mention that stuff declared via `var` inside the viewmodel will not be accessible in the view. Instead it must be attached to `this`.

Comment: I had that covered in the fiddle....Still I updated the answer...thanks for pointing that out.. :)